# Single word for correcting controls out of bounds

Tags: word-request

In a software development environment or page layouting, you can place elements outside the control bounds or outside the page. The coordinates can e.g. have negative values.

We're now introducing a button that moves items outside the visible bounds back to inside. I suggested "Bring all controls into view" and "Adjust clipped controls".

Is there a shorter, e.g. single word that describes the same thing?

Comment: Do you move the elements or the bounds?

Comment: Elements will be moved.

Comment: Are programmers or non-technical users your audience? "clipped controls" is jargon that perhaps few end users would understand. *Bring all controls into view* is better, though not every end user would understand the word "controls" either. Is this utility you're offering for developers during development?

Comment: @TRomano: at the moment this is an advanced feature which will probably be used by our service partners only. They are developers. The application is available to end users, so it would be better if it's also understandable by them. End users hopefully never manage to move items to negative coordinates - that's only done by developers tweaking the settings file manually.

Comment: Does it handle dual-screen setups, when the screens are of different dimensions?

Comment: @TRomano: no, it's not about windows on screens, just about elements (labels, pictures, etc.) on a panel (similar to a UserControl in C# if you know that)

Comment: If you wish non-programmers to understand this brief phrase, and your utility affects any UI element that can be positioned @(x,y) then I have one final question :-)  Is the z-order maintained?  Will using the feature cause UI elements to become superimposed upon other elements? That scenario can cause some end-users to freak out, as if they have broken something. I'm trying to get at how best to phrase "into view".

Comment: @TRomano: yes, it definitely has the freak-out potential. AFAIK, the Z-order is kept as is, so some items may appear over existing elements which are already visible, others might appear below. However, they will be selected and can be brought to front or can be deleted altogether.

Comment: Wow, I'll add more context to the question next time. Didn't know that this would become relevant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are bringing items that are outside a bounded region into that region, then the items are being [*constrained*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=constrain&t=crmtb01).

This term is used more widely than for out-of-bound objects on a printed page but is applicable.

The bounds of the page are the constraints and the act of bringing the objects back into view is to *constrain* them.

Answer (score 0):

Given the need to inform non-technical users (not only programmers) what will happen when they invoke the feature, I'd suggest:

**Show hidden controls (may look jumbled)**

If you want to avoid alarm, perhaps "invisible" instead of "hidden".